Multi Region Keycloak Deployment?
I have deployed keycloak on Region 1 with the write end point as the database(Azure Postgres Flixible Server) URL. Now as I want to configure a DR for my application, I wanted to deploy keycloak on another region too. For that I replicated the database as well. But the db in second region is a read only. So when I connect the keycloak in region 2 to the database in region 2, keycloak crashes. Mostly likely because it is trying to attain a lock on the db using liquibase.
I found docs about Multi-Site Deployment using Infinispan. But seems like it is for multiple zones in a single region.

Not considered: Two regions on the same or different continents, as it would increase the latency and the likelihood of network failures. Synchronous replication of databases as a services with Aurora Regional Deployments on AWS is only available within the same region.

So now the question becomes how do I deploy keycloak in second region as Passive server? I could not find any article on this. Any leads will be helpful.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You connect Keycloak to a RO cluster. It is normal to fail. Have you tried doing a failover with the write endpoint available on region 2 instead?
